# freenas terrible performance 12kb/s read speed

Tags: freenas

I'm getting terribly slow read and write speeds. When I transfer files from the FreeNAS, I get around 12kb/s.

I'm running a ZFS raid with 3 TB drives, 8 GB ram, an atom 1.3 GHz processor. My network is gigabit with Cat6 cables.

Does the processor affect transfer speeds?

What tests can I run to determine if it is the network or the FreeNAS box?

I've seen some commands that can be run but I'm not sure which ones to use.

Comment: Which commands have you seen which you are unsure about?

Comment: What tests can I run to determine if it is the network or the FreeNAS box? - Connect a laptop or other system with a static IP and a crossover cable if needed directly to the FreeNAS box and see if you still get slow speeds.